# How does Django determine field sequence in Model when using positional arguments

Tags: python, django, model

I am wondering if there is a definite sequence for fields when calling a model with positional arguments?

Let's take the standard tutorial example:

```
class Poll(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
```

Standard way to create an object is using keyword arguments, but I can also do this.

```
newPoll = Poll(123, "What is your favorite color?", timezone.now())
```

In this case values are assigned to the fields in this order: "id" , "question" and "pub_date"

My question is how does Django map these positional arguments to the model's field variables? And if there is a consistent logic in this so I could use positional arguments in model class or manager.create method? (It might not be a good idea, just for academic purpose)

I have tried reading the base.py file in Django source, but since I have just started using Django it is taking me some time to understand everything. So if someone could explain this, it would be great.

Answer (score 0):

[The documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/querysets/#create) only refers to the create method as `create(**kwargs)`, so I would view positional args as being undocumented behavior and not reliable for maintainable code.  In my version of Django, that's exactly what the source of `QuerySet` says, so positional arguments won't work, unless there's some magic I'm not seeing, but it could be different from your version.